# Getting Information for Homes on Sale : Real Estate API

Tags: api

Can anyone suggest me :

I am a web developer/computer scientist, trying to build new decision support system for home buying.

Is there any company/API which can provide me API data (XML ) which does the following :

1. For a given zip code : Return the HomeIDs or Homes for sale.
2. For each home give me the home specifications.

Zillow did it, but now they discontinued the GetRegionPostings API, which returned you the HomeIDs of the homes for sale in a given zip code.

Please let me know if any exists around the world.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use Zillow, the GetDeepSearchResults API returns the id for a given address.
http://www.zillow.com/howto/api/GetDeepSearchResults.htm